# Diffrence between node *temp; and node *tmp = new node;

Tags: c++

```
struct node
{
    int data;
    node *next;
} * save;
```

Can anyone explain what's the difference between below declarations, does stack & heap-based memory allocation is the only difference between them or any other?
Can we call both of them as object pointers?

```
node *temp;
```

and

```
node *tmp = new node;
```

Comment: what about c++ ?

Comment: It's a pity that students or new people learning C++ still use this kind of code.

Comment: well I am an Angular Dev & switching to a language like c++ require a decent knowledge of pointers, I guess you already know if are a programmer i think

Comment: It like asking what is the difference between `int n;` and `int n = 10;` Both declare a variable, but only the second one gives that variable a value. It's **exactly** the same for your code. The fact that your variables are pointers makes no difference at all. One of the problems beginners have with pointers is that they think they are somehow special, and different rules apply to pointers, but it's not true.

Comment: @elvis.dukaj The thing about students is, they are studying something in order to gain knowledge about something they don't yet know. Furthermore, even if you should use proper RAII and smart pointers in production code, you still have to know how raw pointers work.

Comment: @john not sure if that is a good analogy. with `int n= 10;` there is only the `int`. In `node* tmp = new node` there are actually two objects, and if you don't delete one of them you have a leak

Comment: @idclev463035818 Yes it's a fair point, but the OP didn't ask about that, and he does appear to be missing the obvious issue about initialisation, which does apply to both pointers and non-pointers.

Comment: @bitmask unfortunately, all new people coming from universities are still stuck in manual memory management and low level synchronization. If you show this technique in smarter way like how to create a container or how to use that for RAII is far way smarter and, the language is also less heavy! Same thing for multi-threading... if teachers show how to use low level construct to build higher structure is again better.

Comment: @elvis.dukaj Teaching C++ is probably **by far** the hardest thing about C++. This is a whole research field, and I honestly couldn't say which way is the better, bottom up or top down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new operator denotes a request for memory allocation on the Free Store. If sufficient memory is available, new operator initializes the memory and returns the address of the newly allocated and initialized memory to the pointer variable.

Syntax to use new operator: To allocate memory of any data type, the syntax is:

```
pointer-variable = new data-type;
```

Here, pointer-variable is the pointer of type data-type. Data-type could be any built-in data type including array or any user defined data types including structure and class.
Example:

```
// Pointer initialized with NULL
// Then request memory for the variable
int *p = NULL; 
p = new int;   

            OR

// Combine declaration of pointer 
// and their assignment
int *p = new int;
```

Comment: Is there any difference between the implementation of these two as in the program both supports temp->next and temp->data operation?

Comment: The first one just created the pointer, not initialized with a new object. after program end, it will automatically be destroyed. while 2nd one explicitly need to be destroyed

Comment: new is not only allocating memory

Answer (score 2):

In your example `node* temp` creates an object of type `node*` with *automatic storage* (see [storage duration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration)).
In the first line this object is uninitialised and in the second you initialise it with a pointer to an object of type `node` that lives in *dynamic storage*.

So in the first example no object of type `node` actually exists. You have only created a pointer that may later refer to such an object.
In any case, when the lifetime of the object named `temp` ends (i.e. when the the scope ends) only the pointer object will be destroyed, never the object that the pointer may point to.

Note that you cannot access members of an object that doesn't exist, so `temp->data` will exhibit [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) if `temp` does not point to an object of type `node`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, they are both pointers to objects, specifically `node`. Now, the pointer itself i.e. both `*temp` and `*tmp` are stack allocated variables that are capable of holding a memory address that can point to an object of type `node`.

Both of these pointers are capable of holding addresses of both dynamically allocated `node` objects created at runtime on the heap as well as local objects on the stack created at compile-time .

```
node stack_alloc_node; 
node* n;
```

Here, `n` is allocated on the stack at compile time and it is capable of holding the address of any `node` object;
I can do this:

```
n = &stack_alloc_node;
```

`stack_alloc_node` is created on the stack at compile time and now `n` holds a reference to it.
Now, let us talk about `new`. When you want to dynamically allocate memory for an object at runtime, you do this:

```
new node;
```

`new` asks the operating system for memory and is given a block of memory by the OS. `new` then returns the address of this memory. Any memory created at runtime can only be referred to through pointers and hence for storing the address of that memory block somewhere, we need pointers:

```
node* temp = new node;
```

A pointer variable that is not assigned is called a **wild pointer** because it may contain an arbitrary address which is useless.

Here, are the 3 elements:

```
node n1;
```

`n1` is a stack-allocated `node` object created at compile time.

```
new node()
```

This is an instruction to the computer to ask for memory and  to create a new `node` object on that memory by calling `node`'s constructor and then to return the address of that memory.

```
node* n2;
```

`n2` is a pointer variable allocated on the stack that is not yet assigned and hence is wild. This pointer is capable of holding addresses of both heap allocated and stack allocated `node`s. You can do both of the following:

```
n2 = new node();
n2 = &n1;
```

In the first scenario, the reference to the newly obtained memory has to be stored and that's what the purpose of `n2` is in the first statement. The second statement is also valid because `n2` is still assigned a pointer but to a stack allocated `node`.
However, the previous code block has a memory leak because all references to that newly created `node` using `new node()` on the heap is lost. You should always:

```
delete n2;
```

to free the associated memory before assigning the pointer to another address. You do not need to delete objects created on the stack because they are automatically destroyed when control goes out of scope. This is not the case with heap allocated objects, they need to be explicitly deleted. In languages like Java and C#, this is automatically handled by the garbage collection sub-system. But C++ does not have one. You can read about smart pointers [here](https://en.cppreference.com/book/intro/smart_pointers) if you want memory to be handled automatically.